# What are starred variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, splat

What are starred variables like `*arr`?

```
*arr = "sayuj"
=> ["sayuj"]

*arr = *%w{i am happy}
=> ["i", "am", "happy"]

*arr = %w{i am happy}
=> [["i", "am", "happy"]]
```

Comment: I removed the "star" and variables tags. They are too ambiguous to help.

Comment: @theTinMan: There's the "splat" tag.

Comment: Yes, there is, with all of 0 followers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called the [splat](http://raflabs.com/blogs/silence-is-foo/2010/08/07/ruby-idioms-what-is-the-splatunary-operator-useful-for/) operator, and it can collect elements into an array (applied to an un-bound variable) or split an array into individual elements (applied to an array).

```
def bar(*a)
  a[1]
end

bar(1,2,3)
=> 2

def foo(a,b,c)
  b
end

foo(*[1,2,3])
=> 2
```

That's a little over-simplified, read the linked post for more in-depth information.

Comment: `a = 1, 2, 3 => [1, 2, 3]`; # Then what is the difference here?

Comment: ruby treats that as a special case - re-read my answer: I changed the first example something to you couldn't do without splat.

Comment: compare these:
a,b = 1,2,3,4; puts b; a,*b = 1,2,3,4; puts b

Comment: pls cross check your first example. that doesn't work. you have to change one of these: `def bar(*a)` => `def bar(a)` or `bar([1, 2, 3])` => `bar(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: shall we use this any where in real time?